# Django - Using function in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to figure out how to create a progress tracker for my users so they can see how many % of the form they have filled out.

I'm stuck not sure how to create the function and then use it / call it in the template.

**Views - calculate progress function**

My function within my class currently looks like this (I've deliberately excluded the form in the class to avoid cluttering):

```
class OpdaterEvalView(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'evalsys/evalueringer/evaluering_forside.html'
    model = Evaluation
    form_class = OpdaterEvalForm

    def calculate_progress(self, evaluation=None):
        value = [evaluation.communication, evaluation.motivate_others,
                 evaluation.development, evaluation.cooperation]
        count = 0
        if value[0]:
            count += 1
        if value[1]:
            count += 1
        if value[2]:
            count += 1
        if value[3]:
            count += 1
        return count * 25
```

The idea is that it will check the array for which values exist in the database and if 0,1,2,3 values exist it will show 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%. I just don't really know how to make this function work in my template? How do I call it? And maybe the function be outside the class? But how do I then target the specific pk of the evaluation.

**Update - more info**

I have an Evaluation model, and a modelForm that is called Relations where I have the four values:

```
 value = [evaluation.eval_relations.communication, evaluation.eval_relations. motivate_others,
                     evaluation.eval_relations.development, evaluation.eval_relations.cooperation]
```

I have a foreignkey to the Evaluation Model called eval_relations.

Comment: seems interesting, maybe you can use django custom template tags (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) or AJAX

Comment: If you want to call the server without a page refresh, then you gotta do something ajax. I'd start by looking at the django-ajax library.

Comment: do you change in percentage while user is filling form or percentage of data saved in database?

Comment: I don't need it to update without a page refresh, as the page will update when the person saves the evaluation and then returns to the "evaluation overview" page where they will be able to see an overview and progress of their evaluation. I've been looking at the template tags..but I'm still struggling to figure out how to make the function work with the template.

Comment: @sandeep Percentage of data from the database when the evaluation is saved

Comment: then you can calculate the percentage by simple percentage rule in view and send it to template. if there is no data for that user, send 0%

Comment: you can count number of "None" in array you defined instead of checking value at every index.

Comment: @sandeep It would be data of the evaluation not the user. Could you elaborate on how to do what you mentioned? I'm not familiar with doing that :)

Comment: If you don't need to pass an argument from the template, make it a property of the view and use `{{view.calculate_progress}}`. The function can of course access any view property via `self`

Answer (score 0):

Here are my assumptions:

A user model

A profile model with 5 fields (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5) and OneToOneField with User model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_name')
    f1 = ...
    .
    .
```

There would be 5 fields in form. We want to to display how many fields are saved in database.

When user first time open the form (when no data saved in profile model), this will show 0% completed.

If user have saved 3 fields earlier, it will show 60%.

I am assuming user (who is filling form) is logged in.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.user_name is None:
        per = 0
    else:
        b = [user.user_name.f1, user.user_name.f2, user.user_name.f3, user.user_name.f4, user.user_name.f5]
        count = 0
        for j in b:
            if j:
                count += 1
        per = count * 20
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormName(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_save = form.save(commit=False)  # assuming you are using ModelForm.
            form_save.user = user  # user is OneToOneField
            form_save.save()
            # if you don't redirect after save, django will show same page after saving.
    else:
        form = FormName()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'per': per
    }
    return render(request, 'templateName.html', context)
```

**template**

```
<h1>{{ per }}% completed</h1>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form  }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I used this to check percentage of profile complete. If you have different condition, please comment.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction. Is it understood correctly that you are saving the modelForm (Profile in this context) which then checks which values exist? I've updated my post with the more correct conditions. I don't use the user as the pk, but rather the Evaluation Model I have, which has a foreign key to a modelForm called Relations, which is what I'm checking the database for values as you mentioned with the profile model.